# cvxpy.Minimize(cvx.sum([cvx.abs(do somthing)...])) Problem.solver return a negative value

Tags: cvxpy

I write some code use `cvxpy`. object function like: `cvxpy.sum([cvx.abs(num1-num2)...])`, solver returns a negative value, should it not be a positive value ?

```py
obj_func.append(cvx.abs(total_tar + cvx.sum(con_expr_neg))) 
obj = cvx.Minimize(cvx.sum(obj_func))
prob = cvx.Problem(obj, constraints)

prob.solve(solver=solver) 
print('result status：' + str(prob.status)) 
print('minimize value：', prob.value) 

result status：optimal 
minimize value： -1.886588863285761e-06 

this my recalculat use common alg： 4.268472548574209e-05
```

Comment: I has added question desc

Comment: Both look like zero to me. One cannot expect miracles from `float`s.

Comment: yes, its look like zero, I want why its is negative, rather than positive? Is it because float overflow or cvxpy.abs's algorithm?

Comment: The people who can answer such questions are at [Computational Science SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com). I would move the question there.